# How to add rows and columns dynamically in a listbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create 1500 rows each having 4 column/cells in list box.
All i wanted to do dynamically.
I have added a listbox using html as
**HTML**

```
<body onload="load()">
<div id="myform">

<select id ="listid" name="mytable" size="5" style="width: 100px;" >
</select>

<input type="button" id="create" value="Click here" onclick="Javascript:addTable()">
<!-- to create a Table and add srows and column JavaScript -->

</div>
</body>
```

**javascript**
note: i am able create row but dont know how to create column.

```
function addTable() {

var nofrow = 1500;
for (var i = 0; i < nofrow; i++) {
     var opt = document.createElement("option");
     document.getElementById("listid").options.add(opt);
   // for (var j = 0; j < noofcell; j++) {
   //           not able to figure out what to add
   //}
}
```

Comment: `<select>` elements don't have columns, just a list of `<option>`s.  Could you explain a bit more about what you mean?  Perhaps you're looking to create a `<table>` dynamically?

Comment: My requirement is to create listbox having rows and column dynamically. Can you help me on it?

Comment: First of all you have to change the HTML structure you need to user DIVs instead on select e.g.
<div class="scrollbox" id="listid">
 <div class="even" id="listid_1">
  <!-- html for table --!>
  <input type="hidden" value="1" name="mytable[]">
 </div>
 <div class="odd" id="listid_2">
  <!-- html for table --!>
  <input type="hidden" value="2" name="mytable[]">
 </div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

```
function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var element1 = document.createElement("input");
  element1.type = "checkbox";
  element1.name="chkbox[]";
  cell1.appendChild(element1);

  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var element2 = document.createElement("input");
  element2.type = "text";
  element2.name = "txtbox[]";
  cell3.appendChild(element2);

}
```

Source [Dynamically Add/Remove Rows In HTML Table Using JavaScript](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript/)

Comment: What is tableid here? how can i add this in listbox? can you explain me with html?

Comment: see the source i have mentioned there, it explains different methods of adding dynamic rows.

Comment: it is in table. how can i add in listbox?